# CMake - How to target include directories for my header file

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to specify include directories for my own header file. For example, I have some external library header files in `path/to/external/include`. For my library, I have a header file `my_lib/foo.h` and a source file `my_lib/foo.cpp`. In `foo.h`, I include headers from the external library:

`my_lib/foo.h`:

```
#include "external.h"
```

Here is the structure of my CMakeLists.txt file:
`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_library(lib1 my_lib/foo.cpp my_lib/foo.h)
target_include_directories(lib1 PUBLIC path/to/external/include)
target_link_libraries(lib1 PUBLIC external_lib)
```

Building results in the error:
`.../foo.h fatal error: external.h: No such file or directory`

However, when including `external.h` in `foo.cpp` INSTEAD of in `foo.h`, the project compiles successfully. I need `external.h` to be included in `foo.h` because `foo.h` relies on the external declarations.

Because of the structure of my project and the external library, I would NOT like to directly include the full path, i.e:

`my_lib/foo.h`:

```
#include "path/to/external/include/external.h"
```

Is there a way to use `target_include_directories` to tell CMake where to find the external headers used in my header file?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `foo.h` is not compiled. Please post the _full_ error message at best with `make VERBOSE=1` or `cmkae --verbose` verbose build output. A .cpp file is compiled, which includes a foo.h file, which includes the external.h file. Which cpp file includes foo.h? Does _that_ cpp file has proper include directorie? There should be "in file included by" "included by" messages from the compiler showing the "include stack". Which compiler are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Simple misunderstanding - I did not realize that I had multiple other .cpp targets that were also dependent on `foo.h`. I only included `foo.h` in `foo.cpp`. I needed to include the directories for those targets as well.

Thank you @KamilCuk for your understanding!